# Scroll custom UITableViewCell to right above keyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, cell

Currently I have a UITableView with custom cells and in each cell there is a UITextField, the problem is that sometimes the UITextField is covered by the UIKeyboard.

So right now I have the Y coordinate for the UIKeyboard and my UITableView is functioning properly with the cells.

So pretty much how can I use that Y coordinate (float), in order to scroll my UITableView to that Y coordinate plus the height of the cell in order to get it right above my UIKeyboard?

Also when I the keyboard hides, how would I reset the UITableView to its normal position that it was in?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[[thetextField superview] superview];
    CGRect cellRect = [cell convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
    float bottomCell = cellRect.origin.y - cellRect.size.height;
    if (bottomCell >= keyboardY) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [thetableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [thetableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: The `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method knows the visible portion of your tableView, so you don't need the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One or the other of [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

I'm guessing that control isn't getting into the if statement. Consider skipping the y-coordinate check in favor of just scrolling the table view regardless of where it is.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[[theTextField superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [theTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
[theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

OK, if you're sure it's getting called, then make sure your indexPath isn't nil, which may happen if cell isn't in the tableView or if it's not a cell.

Comment: I tried the first one and I have the index path and I do UITableViewScrollPositionTop and it doesn't scroll anywhere

Comment: I posted it above :) P.S - That if statement gets called (confirmed with NSLogs)

Comment: Any other ideas? The tableview is definitely connect in IB so I am not sure why this is not working :/

Comment: Hard to say what's going on, I'd say make sure all of your objects are what you think they are, the cell and indexPath as well as theTableView. Post more contextual code if you're inclined.

Comment: Theres no more code to this really and none of the objects are nil and the indexPath of the cell is 1. So I am not sure why it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView adjust itself whenever the keyboard is displayed.

However, it won't do it if you didn't set the `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` of your custom cell to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

i solved by using the below code.

```
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```